# Creating a list of labels using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyenchant

My objective is to create a list of labels(or on big label) such that each label displays a unique output. My program reads the input from a scrolled text and checks for errors and then displays all errors in the form of a list.

```
def check():
    import enchant
    from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
    chkr=SpellChecker("en_US")
    chkr.set_text(str(bd.get("1.0", END)))
    for err in chkr:
            out3=Label(window, text=("ERROR:", err.word), fg="orange", bg="black", font="ariel")
            out3.grid(row=19, column=3, columnspan=5)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804796/7032856) includes a part to create widgets in a list.

Comment: you put all `Labels` in the same place `row=19, column=3` so don't expect you see them. You see only last one. Other labels are hidden behide last one.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, try something like this.

```
    y = 19
    for err in chkr:
        Label(window, text = "your error", fg="orange", bg="black", font="ariel").grid(row=y, column=3, columnspan=5)
        y = y + 1
```